# how to use Laravel 8 query builder like eloquent for searching

Tags: php, laravel, search, eloquent, query-string

I'm developing a simple CRM with Laravel 8 that needs to search in query string.

My query string would be look like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/users/supervisor?q=john&gender=m
```

Now the problem is how can I search in controller?

I want to do like this:

```
public function index (Request $request)
{
    $role = getRoleCode($request->role);
    $roles = Role::where('role', '=', $role);

    if ($request->q) {
        $roles->where('name', 'like', "%$request->$q%");
    }

    if ($request->gender) {
        $roles->where('gender', '=', $request->gender);
    }

    $role->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20);

    return view('admin.users.index', [
        'roles' => $roles,
        'role_name' => config('settings.roles')[$role],
        'role_en_name' => $request->role,
        'q' => $request->q,
        'gender' => $request->gender
    ]);
}
```

I wonder why its not working and what is the standard way to do this.

I've tried:

```
Role::query();
```

but that didn't work either.

I've also tried:

```
$roles = Role::where('role', '=', $role)
    ->where('name', 'like', "%$request->$q%")
    ->where('gender', '=', $request->gender)
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->paginate(20);
```

This codes works perfectly but we may not be sending the "q" or "gender" URL params.

PS: Sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: you aren't saving the result of the call to `paginate` which returns the result, you are passing the builder to your view, not the result of the query ... and you seem to be confusing `$role` and `$roles` in your code ... though i guess this seems to be "pseudo code"?

Comment: If you're going to be chaining a Query based on conditionals, I find naming your Query differently than the result helps a lot, like `$query = Role::where('role', $role);`, then in each `if` statement: `$query->where(...)`, and when you're done, `$results = $query->latest('id')->paginate(20);`. That way, `$query` and `$result` are distinctly different. `$role` and `$roles`, with method chaining, etc. can (and is) lead to some confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to conditionally add `where` statements to your query you can use the `if` statements like you are attempting to do or use the `when` method of the Eloquent/Query Builder:

```
$roles = Role::where('role', $role)
    ->when($request->input('q'), fn ($query, $search) => $query->where('name', 'like', '%'. $search .'%'))
    ->when($request->input('gender'), fn ($query, $gender) => $query->where('gender', $gender))
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(20);
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Queries - Conditional Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses) `when`

Answer (score 1):

work with when() it's better

```
->when(true, function($query){$query->where('x', x);})
```